# What does the Flash VM use under the hood for drawing?

Tags: graphics, flash, virtual-machine

In windows, what does Flash use under the hood?

It's a relatively simple question which I can never find the answer to.  Is it GDI (for windows VM implementations) or something else?

You don't need to go into any of the new GPU acceleration features of Flash.  I just really want to know the inner workings because it's NEVER discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 64-bit Linux, the Flash plugin does not link against SDL (according to `ldd`).  It does, however, link against GTK, GDK, and Cairo.  It appears, therefore, that it is using either Cairo or raw Xlib calls to do its drawing on Linux.

I don't know on Windows.  Flash tends to have minimal dependencies, but Direct-X may be standard enough that they use it.  With some kind of a process examiner to tell you what libraries a process has loaded, you could examine a simple web browser embedding Flash and see what system facilities are actually in use.

Comment: interesting answers all around.  Thanks guys. 

You were one of the last answers, but you have the most complete answer so marked as the answer for future generations =)

Answer (score 1):

DirectX mostly. It's hard to achieve good graphics performance with GDI.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with george, GDI is very bad for speed. DirectX for Windows and SDL or similar for Linux (note this is an assumption!). In that sense it probably uses a layer that communicates with the native graphics subsystem on whatever platform it's running on.